# Google analytics get realtime report

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

Hii… i wanted to get the realtime reports of the google analytics that they have displyed in their website… i tried using google analytics api to retrieve the data using dimensions and metrics… is there any other method to retrieve the data from google analytics dashboard to reactjs app…

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options to export your analytics data:

- [CSV/PDF export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9317657?hl=en) - allows you to export aggregate analytics data as shown in the reports from your Firebase console.
- [BigQuery export](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) - allows you to access your raw, unsampled event data along with all of your parameters and user properties. Data is exported to BigQuery on a daily basis.

For server to server setup, I would suggest using the [Google Analytics 4 Measurement Protocol API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). The Measurement Protocol API allows you to make HTTP requests to send events directly to Google Analytics servers and allows you to measure how users interact with your business from any HTTP-enabled environment. This makes it easy to measure interactions that happen server-to-server.